# Can I have a single-spa container inside another single-spa container?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I am exploring and prototyping on single-spa framework and with multiple micro-apps managed and deployed independently. I have the code published on https://github.com/agrawald/micro-frontend-single-spa.

However, I was wondering if we can have a container single-spa inside another container single-spa?

Answer (score 1):

https://single-spa.js.org/docs/faq/#should-i-have-a-parentroot-app-and-children-apps

single-spa maintainers strongly discourage nesting single-spa applications. Some [nomenclature](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/module-types) is useful to understand the recommendation.

Single-spa maintainers recommend using "[cross-microfrontend imports](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#cross-microfrontend-imports)" to share components between registered-applications whenever they are written in the same framework and [single-spa parcels](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/parcels-overview) when they are written in different frameworks.

In short the recommendation is to share components and do not try to nest single-spa applications. Or put another all registered applications are siblings in a hierarchy that can share components when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve a similar functionality by using [parcels](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/parcels-overview). These are components from one micro frontend that can be referenced / included in other micro frontends.