Register/load micro-frontend app within micro-frontend app using Single-SPA
I'm using Single-SPA and I would like to be able to have one Micro-frontend (MFE) load another.
I have a root app that displays a couple angular MFEs on the screen, so I know how to do that without a problem. But I want one of my angular MFEs to be able to open a popup that displays a different MFE.
So with Single-SPA angular, how can I make my MFE 1 angular app display a popup and put MFE 2 angular app inside it? Like this pic:

I'm not sure if Parcels is the right solution here. According to the docs, that's meant for displaying multi-framework components, but MFE 1 and 2 are both angular. I'm also not sure if parcels are meant for loading MFE apps? It kinda seems like they're just meant for components, not whole apps?
This question seems close to mine, but the answer doesn't really answer my question so I couldn't make much of it: Creating Structural Micro Frontend Using single-spa

I just ran across this question so I'm starting to think maybe it's not possible (or at least not "recommended", whatever that means):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58637426/can-i-have-a-single-spa-container-inside-another-single-spa-container
